# Square root using simple arithmetic shift, inversion etc

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, arithmetic

Suppose we have a function which is sampled by a sampling time 10ms. This function comes in to the computer, then this computer should calculate square root (for every sampling time) from that function.

[image]

$ g^*(t) = \sqrt{f^*(t)}$

Here $f^*$ and $g^*$ are sampled signals (discrete)

**Only these operations are possible:**

Arithmetic shift,
inversion,
bit wise

Is there any well know square root calculation algorithms appropriate for this situation?

Comment: You didn't specify how the signal is stored. Is it a binary representation of an int? a float?

Comment: it can be both unsigned int and unsigned short.

Comment: You could use this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shifting_nth-root_algorithm
But I'll be flagging this over to comp sci @ SE.